# Are user-hierarchies used by analysis services to determine what to aggregate?

Tags: ssas, cube

I'm trying to understand how analysis services determines which aggregations to compute when processing a cube. From what I have read it seems as if user-defined hierarchies are used for this purpose in that aggregations are pre-computed based on their structure. In contrast to this, attribute hierarchies do not contribute towards this pre-computation.

A [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7236111/1308942) has been posed here but I was wondering whether there are any other resources online that explain this in more detail.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tremendous paper that every SSAS developer should read... [SQL Server 2008 White Paper: Analysis Services Performance Guide](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17303)

> Analysis Services enables you to build **two types of user
>   hierarchies: natural and unnatural hierarchies**, each with different
>   design and performance characteristics. In a **natural hierarchy**,
>   all attributes participating as levels in the hierarchy **have direct
>   or indirect attribute relationships from the bottom of the hierarchy
>   to the top of the hierarchy**.
>
> In an **unnatural hierarchy**, the hierarchy consists of at least two
>   consecutive levels that **have no attribute relationships**. Typically
>   these hierarchies are used to create drill-down paths of commonly
>   viewed attributes that do not follow any natural hierarchy. For
>   example, users may want to view a hierarchy of Gender and Education.
>
> From a performance perspective, natural hierarchies behave very
>   differently than unnatural hierarchies. In **natural hierarchies**,
>   the hierarchy tree is **materialized on disk** in hierarchy stores. In
>   addition, **all attributes participating in natural hierarchies are
>   automatically %CONSIDERED% to be aggregation candidates**.
>
> **Unnatural hierarchies are not materialized on disk**, and the attributes participating in unnatural hierarchies are **not
>   automatically considered as aggregation candidates**. Rather, they
>   simply provide users with easy-to-use drill-down paths for commonly
>   viewed attributes that do not have natural relationships. By
>   assembling these attributes into hierarchies, you can also use a
>   variety of MDX navigation functions to easily perform calculations
>   like percent of parent.

Also, being "considered" as an aggregation candidate DOES NOT mean the attribute will actually be used in an aggregation.  Download the paper in the top link...read it and pay special attention to the "Aggregation Usage Rules" and "Influencing Aggregation Candidates" sections.

fwiw, in production, most developers start the aggregation wizard and eventually switch over to Usage-Based Optimization.